# How to rotate an image in reStructuredText?

Tags: restructuredtext

Is there an option to the command

```
.. image:: picture.png
```

like

```
:rot: 90degrees
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. But you could [apply a custom class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32079200/2214933) using [`class`](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#class) and use [CSS to rotate the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674086/rotate-image-with-css).