# How to make an image fit the height of a container when rotated?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have an image which I rotate with css `rotate` property to `90deg`.

Problem, once rotated, the image keep its size and is bigger than the container.

How to fix this with `TailwindCSS` ?

Here is a [playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/s3bQu7zvvp)

Here is the code :

```
<div class="p-8">
  <div class="h-[315px] w-[560px] border-2 border-solid">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/1900x800" class="h-full w-full rotate-90 transform object-fill" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674086/how-to-rotate-image-with-css-only

Comment: Do you have the option to wrap the image with an additional `<div>`?

Comment: @stickyuser yes I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrap the image in a `<div>` and rotate that, you can then set the image to `object-contain` so the image fits the height of the container.

```
<div class="p-8">
  <div class="h-[315px] w-[560px] border-2 border-solid">
    <div class="h-[560px] w-[315px] origin-top-left translate-x-[560px] rotate-90">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/1900x800" class="h-full w-full object-contain" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/CXZoglKryG